# Print button click event Active Reports

Tags: c#, activereports

I'm working in `Active Reports` and now I need to throw an alert during the print button click in `SectionReport`.

I can see the `PrintProgress` and `PrintAborted` event, but i need a event like `PrintStart`

Or

Is there anyway to access the `button click` event of print?

Something like this,

```
private void TestReport_Print(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for using ActiveReports.
You can customize the viewer toolbar to modify the behavior of the toolbar buttons and capture the click events as described in this article

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.Viewer+ViewerToolbar~MainBar.html

Comment: Working picture perfect. But the `Toolbar.MainBar` is obsolete. We have to use `ToolStrip` instead. Kindly clarify.

Comment: I answered your other question regarding toolstrip.   it is now on Viewer.Toolbar.Toolstrip